# How to send data with XMLHttpRequest without passing data as parameter

Tags: javascript, servlets, xmlhttprequest

Currently I am sending the data as parameter in `URL`.

Ex

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/test?param1=" + param1Value+ "&param2="+ param2Value;
```

I am using `XMLHttpRequest` to communicated.

But by doing this I can see the params in requested `URL`.

How can I send the data without passing as parameter? (Basically how do I hide those data).

And on server how do I retrieve that?

Comment: You can't hide Data that is on the client side, at least not practically

Comment: Use Ajax request

Comment: You answer your question in the question.  You POST it.  The Url you show is a GET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use jquery to create a POST form, fill it up, and submit it on the fly.

```js
$("body").append("<form id='form1' action='http://localhost:8080/test' method='POST'></form>");

$("<input></input>", {
 "type": "text",
 "name": "param1",
 "value": param1Value
}).appendTo("#form1");

$("<input></input>", {
 "type": "text",
 "name": "param2",
 "value": param2Value
}).appendTo("#form1");

var theForm = $("#form1");
theForm.hide();
theForm.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks will try this